# Converting 4 space to 2 space in Xcode

Tags: xcode

How easy is it to convert 4 spaces to 2 spaces indent in Xcode at once in the whole project? Maybe there exists a tool or script? I tried to convert manually (control + i) each file, but I need to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline replacement running the following command in your terminal, just make it find the required files first:

```
find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i '' 's/    /  /g'
```